# Basic axiom confusion

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

In mathematical logic,we do know that some statement is unprovable.Such as 0=1 in Peano Arithmetic system.

However,there is still one thing I want to know,let's concentrate our attention on Peano Arithmetic.

Can we prove the consistency of those basic axioms of Peano Arithmetic system(such as the commutative and associative of addition and multiplication)?Intuitively,I mean can we prove that those axioms are not violate to each other?
Please include a reason briefly,I am just a beginner on logic.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. The commutative and associative properties of addition and multiplication are *not* axioms of Peano Arithmetic. They are *theorems* which are proved.

Comment: How do you define multiplication and addition in PA ?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: it is common to axiomatize PA by starting with the axioms of a discrete ordered semiring; these axioms are then called the "basic axioms", $PA^{-}$. Full PA is obtained by also including the induction scheme. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic

Comment: @CarlMummert Thank you. I was only aware of the Peano axioms in the context of second-order logic.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: no problem, this is a common misunderstanding often conveyed by textbooks. In second-order logic we can start with just the successor operation and build from there. But in first-order logic neither addition nor multiplication is definable from just the successor operation - they are implicitly definable, but not actually definable in the way necessary to adjoin them to a model. So we have to start with the addition and multiplication function symbols and some set of axioms for them.

Comment: @CarlMummert Thank you, once again, for spending some time explaining this to me.

Comment: $0 \neq 1$ follows trivially from Peano's Axioms. We define $1=S(0)$. We obtain a contradiction if we assume $0=1$.

Answer (score 2):

We can prove the relative consistency of the PA axioms. Assuming a model of set theory, we can construct inside that model a model of PpA. That show that if the axioms of set theory are consistent, then so are the PA axioms.

Comment: :do you mean we need to construct a even more large model which include PA system to prove the consistency of PA system,but we cannot prove it's own consistency(i.e.axioms do not violate each other)in it's own.

Comment: Yes, but that should not be a surprise. You can’t create something from nothing, so yes. Showing the axioms are consistent is equivalent to consstructing a model. Constructing anything at all requires previous things to exist. So, if you are going to construct a model of something you must do so by using a model of something else. Such is life.

Comment: Ittay Weiss:Can you give me a simple deduction why we cannot prove whether those axioms are violated to each other or not?You can use Gödel's second incompleteness theorem directly

Comment: Do you need to go to the loo? Your post seems to be overflowing with an excessive amount of p. :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain if you're asking how to prove PA is consistent, or how to prove that the basic axioms of PA are consistent.

There are at least three different proof methods to show that PA is consistent:

- The most straightforward is to work in set theory, such as ZFC, and prove that PA has a model.  Because this set theory also proves the soundness of first-order logic, this means the set theory proves that PA cannot derive $0=1$.
- There are also syntactic proofs of the consistency of PA. These proofs directly show that there is no derivation of $0=1$ from the axioms of PA, without generating a model. The first syntactic consistency proof was due to Gentzen. It uses transfinite induction up to an ordinal known as $\epsilon_0$. Gentzen's consistency proof set the stage for what is now called "ordinal analysis" in proof theory.
- The second syntactic consistency proof is due to Gödel. It uses very different methods, including the so-called *Dialectica* interpretation. It is again syntactic: it does not produce a model of PA.

In every case, to prove the consistency of PA we have to use some axioms that are not included in PA. This is due to the second incompleteness theorem, which shows that PA cannot prove its own consistency.  The second and third methods assume much less beyond PA, in a particular sense, than the first.

PA itself proves that the set of basic axioms of PA is consistent. In fact, PA has a stronger property: for any finite set $F$ of axioms of PA, PA proves that $F$ is consistent. So we do not need to move to particularly strong systems to prove that the basic axioms of PA are consistent.

Comment: :It is always hard to express my question in the area of logic for me.I will try to formalize my question:let M be a system only include two axioms X and Y.Then what I want to ask is why X⊃~Y is not provable in system M?

Comment: In some axiom systems it could be provable, e.g. if $X$ is "$\lnot Y \land \lnot Y$". In that case the axioms $X$ and $Y$ are inconsistent. In the case of Peano Arithmetic, the proof that the axioms are (mutually) consistent is not trivial.